# Zooming & Panning Issue Translate/ScaleTransform WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, zooming

I have a canvas control and I am dynamically adding different shapes in it.I have implemented zooming by using ScaleTransform and panning by TranslateTransform.If I have to zoom in and out without resizing the shapes in canvas ( i.e resizing the canvas without resizing its children ), how would I achieve that ?

Thanks,

BR,

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I think pasting the code won't help.I haven't done anything which needs to be corrected, suggest me something , that is what I want to ask.

Comment: If you haven't done anything you should not ask others for help. Have a look at most of the post with negative score. You will find out most of the comments are asking **what have you tried?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following simple derived Canvas would arrange its child elements at transformed positions given by their `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` property value. The transform is applied by a `ChildPositionTransform` dependency property.

```
public class ZoomCanvas : Canvas
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildPositionTransformProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ChildPositionTransform", typeof(Transform), typeof(ZoomCanvas),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                Transform.Identity, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange));

    public Transform ChildPositionTransform
    {
        get { return (Transform)GetValue(ChildPositionTransformProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChildPositionTransformProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement element in InternalChildren)
        {
            var x = GetLeft(element);
            var y = GetTop(element);
            var pos = new Point(double.IsNaN(x) ? 0d : x, double.IsNaN(y) ? 0d : y);
            ArrangeElement(element, ChildPositionTransform.Transform(pos));
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    private void ArrangeElement(UIElement element, Point position)
    {
        element.Arrange(new Rect(position, element.DesiredSize));
    }
}
```

Now you may also take the child element's `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties into account, by refining the ArrangeElement method.

```
private void ArrangeElement(UIElement element, Point position)
{
    if (element is FrameworkElement)
    {
        switch (((FrameworkElement)element).HorizontalAlignment)
        {
            case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                position.X -= element.DesiredSize.Width / 2;
                break;

            case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                position.X -= element.DesiredSize.Width;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        switch (((FrameworkElement)element).VerticalAlignment)
        {
            case VerticalAlignment.Center:
                position.Y -= element.DesiredSize.Height / 2;
                break;

            case VerticalAlignment.Bottom:
                position.Y -= element.DesiredSize.Height;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    element.Arrange(new Rect(position, element.DesiredSize));
}
```